# Checking Hardware RAID status Live

Tags: linux, raid, ibm-hmc

I want to check the Hardware `RAID` status of my host. I know there is a way to check it from the Server Vendor has their own command line utility for checking the performing of all the physical devices.

Is there any third party Package which can give me the status of my current `RAID`.

Edited as per the Answer `smartctl` not working

```
# lspci | egrep -i 'raid|adaptec'
01:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2008 [Falcon] (rev 03)

# smartctl -d scsi --all /dev/sg1 -H
smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [x86_64-linux-2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

Vendor:               IBM
Product:              ServeRAID M1015
Revision:             2.12
User Capacity:        597,998,698,496 bytes [597 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Logical Unit id:      0x600605b003e420c016766a6e4652e202
Serial number:        0002e252466e6a7616c020e403b00506
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Thu Mar  3 21:26:11 2016 IST
Device does not support SMART

Error Counter logging not supported
Device does not support Self Test logging
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find and install `storcli` package in my Server and now I am able to find the drive failure.

Below is the step to follow

```
[root@GURUWEBII tmp]# rpm -ivh storcli-1.03.11-1.noarch.rpm
    Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
            package storcli-1.03.11-1.noarch is installed

[root@GURUWEBII tmp]# /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0 show all

PD LIST :
=======

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG       Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model            Sp
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
64:0      8 Onln   0 278.464 GB SAS  HDD N   N  512B MBF2300RC        U
64:1     12 Onln   0 278.464 GB SAS  HDD N   N  512B MBF2300RC        U
64:2     10 UBad   - 278.464 GB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST9300603SS      U
64:3      9 Onln   0 278.464 GB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST9300603SS      U
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

EID-Enclosure Device ID|Slt-Slot No.|DID-Device ID|DG-DriveGroup
DHS-Dedicated Hot Spare|UGood-Unconfigured Good|GHS-Global Hotspare
UBad-Unconfigured Bad|Onln-Online|Offln-Offline|Intf-Interface
Med-Media Type|SED-Self Encryptive Drive|PI-Protection Info
SeSz-Sector Size|Sp-Spun|U-Up|D-Down|T-Transition|F-Foreign
```

Sample output of my disk which was failed.

Comment: If it's an LSI-built RAID controller you can also use the `lsiutil` utility if you can find it.  Google for it.  And if you do find it, be *careful* using it - you can brick your controller with it.

Comment: Ohhh is it, I will surely be careful with that. which one is best and safe `lsiutil`  or `storcli64`

Answer (score 0):

You can use smartctl. The command is different is you are behind one or other controller. See this links:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-checking-sas-sata-disks-behind-adaptec-raid-controllers/

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-freebsd-3w-9xxx-smartctl-check-hard-disk-command/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have edited the link with my output.

Comment: I am getting error `Error Counter logging not supported`. I have a disk failure on this system. this is right time to test for me. So that I can use this ins the future.